# what is a proper way to maintain a network connection that different views will use?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to connect to some arbitrary device via wifi from a "connection" view. When pressing "back" and returning to the main menu, I want the connection I created to still exist(so that other views of the app can send/recive messages through it like ssh or telnet). Is it a good idea to create a connection (with say CFNetwork or such) in a separate thread or NSOperation and pass a reference to this thread to the main menu view controller?

Comment: I tend to make a special class (`ConnectionManager`) that handles all the connection related stuff and use it as a singleton. Possibly called `[ConnectionManager sharedManager]` or such. In combination with another (also used as singleton object) `DataModel` class you can access all your data & requests from any part of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to design your app in such a way that each separate group of functions are in a separate class. For example, as mentioned above, use a separate class for connections. You can use the Singleton pattern in order to create 1 instance only for your app to use from anywhere.
Also instead of worrying about NSOperations...which would be calls within your class, you can use a well-tested framework and off you go. You'll find it here with examples...

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

---

@interface  NetworkConnections: NSObject

@end

@implementation NetworkConnections

- (id)sharedInstance
  {
  // structure used to test whether the block has completed or not
  static dispatch_once_t p = 0;

  // initialize sharedObject as nil (first call only)
  __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;

  // executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application
  dispatch_once(&p, ^{
      _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
  });

  // returns the same object each time
  return _sharedObject;
  }
- (void) doSomething {

}

@end

Anytime you want to use that class:

[[NetworkConnections sharedInstance]  doSomething];

Comment: is it advisable to make the singleton object global? If not, whats a recommended way of making it accessible to all other classes that will use it, passing it in as a parameter upon initialization?